# Sed: use found string as a variable

Tags: sed, text-processing

I'm looking for a way to replace all instances of a form:

```
model->variable
```

with

```
models[variable][index]
```

where variable can be pretty much any combination of letters and numbers, probably defined like [0-9a-Z]{4,12}.
There are hundreds of such variables in the text. I need to know exact form of found string "variable" to use it in replacement. Is there a way to "remember" the string and use it later? Or any other method / software which could help in such case?

Thanks in advance.

If you could convert "variable" to uppercase by the way, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use things in the pattern to replace with if you enclose it in `\(...\)`. You then use `\1` to insert the thing that was captured by the first such bracket.

A naïve solution to your problem would be this:

```
sed 's/model->\(.*\)/models[\1][index]/' file.txt
```